# I have a minimal API in .NET Core 6.0 using ADO.NET in a repository pattern

Tags: c#, ado.net, .net-6.0, connection-string, minimal-apis

I'm utilizing a Minimal API with a Service which calls a repository in .NET Core 6.0. I want to be able to pass a connection string to my repository.

Here's the tree of my project:

[image]

The idea is the program has the endpoints which call the service which then calls the repository.

I'm trying to get the connection string from the repository.

In `program.cs`, I'm using a builder as follows:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
...
var app = builder.Build();
```

Methods that look like this:

```
app.MapPost("/create",
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, Roles = 
"Administrator")]
(Movie movie, IMovieService service) => Create(movie, service))
.Accepts<Movie>("application/json")
.Produces<Movie>(statusCode: 200, contentType: "application/json");
```

And methods being used by these functions that look like this:

```
IResult Create(Movie movie, IMovieService service)
{
    var result = service.Create(movie);
    return Results.Ok(result);
}
```

Then there's some methods on the service which look like this:

```
namespace MinimalJwt.Services
{
    public class MovieService : IMovieService
    {
        private readonly MovieRepository movieRepository = new MovieRepository();

        public Movie Create(Movie movie)
        {
            movie = movieRepository.CreateNewMovie(movie);
            return movie;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally The way I'm trying to make my repository which looks like this right now

```
namespace MinimalJwt.Repositories
{
    public class MovieRepository : IMovie
    {
        public IConfiguration _configuration;
        
        public MovieRepository(IConfiguration config)
        {
            this._configuration = config;
        }

        public IList<Movie> GetMovies()
        {
            List<Movie> movies = new List<Movie>();

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("MoviesContextDb")))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetAllMovies", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                con.Open();

                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    var movie = new Movie()
                    {
                        Id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Id"]),
                        Title = rdr["Title"].ToString(),
                        Description = rdr["Description"].ToString(),
                        Rating = Convert.ToDouble(rdr["Rating"])
                    };

                    movies.Add(movie);
                }

                return (movies);
            }
      }
}
```

The idea is for the repository to be able to use the connection string inside of `appsettings.json`.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the actual error/issue you're having?

Answer (score 0):

Your appsettings.json files should be look like this. Then your code should work.

```
{ 
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MoviesContextDb": "Connection String details"
  }
   //.....other configurations.........
}
```